# Bootstrap sub-theme navbar buttons

Tags: navigation

It looks like when you use the default Bootstrap subtheme, it renders a navbar with the Main Menu links at the top of the page, as `<li><a>...</a></li>` elements inside of a navbar-nav block. How can one, instead of using `<li><a>...`, instead use `<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">...</a></li>`, so that my navbar has links styled as buttons instead of normal links?

I'm using the Bootstrap 7.x-3.0 subtheme. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to add a class btn just to make it a button? Can't you just use the following css:

```
#navbar ul a {}
```

and style that to make it look like a button?